# Dart program to group consecutive number from given numbers in a list<list>

Tags: list, algorithm, dart, math

Suppose you are given a list of numbers like this

`[11,2,7,6,17,13,8,9,3,5,12]`

The result will be a group of numbers list containing sub-list i.e.,

`[[2,3],[5,6,7,8,9],[11,12,13],[17]]`

Comment: `[for (var i in (list..sort()).splitBetween((a, b) => a + 1 != b)) [...i]]` (using the yet-unreleased extension methods from [package:collection](https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/blob/master/lib/src/iterable_extensions.dart#L442)).

Comment: Very elegant, I love it thank's. Didn't find it on the online docs makes sense now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my solution to the problem:

```dart
List<List<int>> consecutive_groups(List<int> a) {
  a.sort();
  List<List<int>> result = [];
  List<int> temp = [];
  temp.add(a[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if (a[i + 1] == a[i] + 1) {
      temp.add(a[i + 1]);
    } else {
      result.add(temp);
      temp = [];
      temp.add(a[i + 1]);
    }
  }

  result.add(temp);

  return result;
}
```